# FormLayout caption TextField on top?

Tags: java, frameworks, vaadin, vaadin7

There's some way to set captions on the top of TextField using FormLayout on vaadin7 ?
I think that default caption is only the left but I need change that.

Any idea ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FormLayout` always puts captions left of the field. Moreover it has also a column for the error indicator. Other layouts such as `VerticalLayout` or `HorizontalLayout` put the caption above the field.

If you want to control the position of your caption you could

1. deal with labels
2. use a CustomLayout